# Dotnet: Unknown Solution Item Type opening Solution file on Mac M1

Tags: c#, .net, macos, visual-studio

I've been struggling open a solution file that references the following dotnet project system guid - `9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556`

[image: Error message in VS]

Project Solution File:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.2.32526.322
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Bsg.Infra.Common", "src\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.Common\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.Common.csproj", "{6867E0E4-B740-453E-B195-25A9E2295ADA}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Bsg.Infra.EntityFramework", "src\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.EntityFramework\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.EntityFramework.csproj", "{5F79D2CF-1885-4389-B325-897B5E20B17F}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Bsg.Infra.WebJob", "src\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.WebJob\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.WebJob.csproj", "{71D52BC7-CD96-4786-8802-12537870F73C}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Bsg.Infra.Http", "src\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.Http\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.Http.csproj", "{8F40200E-A0BE-4AED-913A-318DEB3428E7}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Infra Libs", "Infra Libs", "{17199618-C1A9-4A6F-9C00-70DF2E17ADEE}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "App Libs", "App Libs", "{6F0BE538-53B1-4551-BA7A-7F687900BCD6}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Runtime Hosts", "Runtime Hosts", "{85C8C31B-D9BD-465D-8F3E-2AC4FF5C3095}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Deploy Hosts", "Deploy Hosts", "{8FA14344-9768-4E6C-A735-3353867240AF}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Solution Items", "Solution Items", "{E506C5A9-8B4C-4D6C-9F4A-9B78A39BEF2A}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        .editorconfig = .editorconfig
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.Host.Api", "src\Tsp.Sizamina.Host.Api\Tsp.Sizamina.Host.Api.csproj", "{9AD909E2-6528-494D-83F3-E9F9BA21EA59}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.Host.Scheduler", "src\Tsp.Sizamina.Host.Scheduler\Tsp.Sizamina.Host.Scheduler.csproj", "{DF22E1D0-12B5-4AE1-8507-C20E250E824A}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.Host.Worker", "src\Tsp.Sizamina.Host.Worker\Tsp.Sizamina.Host.Worker.csproj", "{5957E137-84AE-4F53-9F7A-BCFD9AAF6947}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.App.Http", "src\Tsp.Sizamina.App.Http\Tsp.Sizamina.App.Http.csproj", "{92E2BB7D-CA78-4759-9F96-3CA71AD62AD9}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.App.EntityFramework", "src\Tsp.Sizamina.App.EntityFramework\Tsp.Sizamina.App.EntityFramework.csproj", "{3169C948-DC41-4B05-8625-25F7D0D69026}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.App.WebJob", "src\Tsp.Sizamina.App.WebJob\Tsp.Sizamina.App.WebJob.csproj", "{A0423A13-7426-4093-8BC9-D39FA3A5246D}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.Deploy.Utility", "src\Tsp.Sizamina.Deploy.Utility\Tsp.Sizamina.Deploy.Utility.csproj", "{3F4BD2C9-E968-4FDE-86F6-5AB739795420}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Test", "Test", "{D1C6BD19-0545-4D07-816A-F1A4281F0C6F}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.Tests.Unit", "test\Tsp.Sizamina.Tests.Unit\Tsp.Sizamina.Tests.Unit.csproj", "{C66C049D-6A02-4BF5-9E7F-00090A946D7D}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Bsg.Infra.ServiceBus", "src\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.ServiceBus\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.ServiceBus.csproj", "{8B8FB296-1A96-4FAA-A982-A9B34BE9F241}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.App.ServiceBus", "src\Tsp.Sizamina.App.ServiceBus\Tsp.Sizamina.App.ServiceBus.csproj", "{E7E90EC5-30A7-458D-A593-960F75755C91}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Bsg.Infra.Graph", "src\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.Graph\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.Graph.csproj", "{5A4798C6-EFE7-43DA-B3AF-1DA75715FD68}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.App.Graph", "src\Tsp.Sizamina.App.Graph\Tsp.Sizamina.App.Graph.csproj", "{EA3B55B7-65A7-4B57-A249-7265DA83E942}"
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Web", "Web", "{2A831C90-C09E-49B3-A948-BA43E6C16208}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        support\Web\appsettings.template.js = support\Web\appsettings.template.js
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "DevOps", "DevOps", "{020D2761-F1E4-417B-AFEA-94FE65E6A40F}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        support\DevOps\azure-pipelines.common.yml = support\DevOps\azure-pipelines.common.yml
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "CodeQuality", "CodeQuality", "{404CE659-A8CC-4807-9F1F-6E721B676A22}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        CodeAnalysis.ruleset = CodeAnalysis.ruleset
        Tsp.Sizamina.sln.DotSettings = Tsp.Sizamina.sln.DotSettings
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Deploy", "Deploy", "{0B002E0E-AD56-4DD3-BF38-B15A53640391}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        support\Utility\Commands.txt = support\Utility\Commands.txt
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "SourceControl", "SourceControl", "{36EF4B96-316C-4135-A8AE-D24DE5BA7725}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        .gitignore = .gitignore
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Getting Started", "Getting Started", "{BC8A449A-189B-48EF-AB6B-DD8680DE3DA4}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        support\Asterix\Asterix Getting Started.txt = support\Asterix\Asterix Getting Started.txt
        README.md = README.md
        support\Azure\Sizamina Azure Setup Guide.txt = support\Azure\Sizamina Azure Setup Guide.txt
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Sql", "Sql", "{C3065E25-438F-4093-B37B-3BC85B154E46}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        support\SQL\Update_Platform_Connections.sql = support\SQL\Update_Platform_Connections.sql
        support\SQL\Update_Solution_Connections.sql = support\SQL\Update_Solution_Connections.sql
        support\SQL\xxx_SIZAMINA_migration_template.sql = support\SQL\xxx_SIZAMINA_migration_template.sql
    EndProjectSection
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Bsg.Infra.SendGrid", "src\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.SendGrid\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.SendGrid.csproj", "{98750BF6-5FDE-4F82-B625-8C3B9DC9B065}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Bsg.Infra.Csv", "src\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.Csv\Tsp.Bsg.Infra.Csv.csproj", "{593FAB70-649A-4CDB-A145-3F0A58115A9D}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.App.Csv", "src\Tsp.Sizamina.App.Csv\Tsp.Sizamina.App.Csv.csproj", "{7DAAA607-FA2B-4039-9627-85870A8621F3}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.App.SharedServices", "src\Tsp.Sizamina.App.SharedServices\Tsp.Sizamina.App.SharedServices.csproj", "{60DF8EA9-6C0D-4E70-8C9C-B14790196D15}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.App.SharedModels", "src\Tsp.Sizamina.App.SharedModels\Tsp.Sizamina.App.SharedModels.csproj", "{B3413D98-BAE0-48C1-A773-DBD13FE691C8}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "Tsp.Sizamina.App.Report", "src\Tsp.Sizamina.App.Report\Tsp.Sizamina.App.Report.csproj", "{DFAD4741-9711-4446-BABE-BC6F8FAB07F5}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {6867E0E4-B740-453E-B195-25A9E2295ADA}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {6867E0E4-B740-453E-B195-25A9E2295ADA}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {6867E0E4-B740-453E-B195-25A9E2295ADA}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {6867E0E4-B740-453E-B195-25A9E2295ADA}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {5F79D2CF-1885-4389-B325-897B5E20B17F}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {5F79D2CF-1885-4389-B325-897B5E20B17F}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {5F79D2CF-1885-4389-B325-897B5E20B17F}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {5F79D2CF-1885-4389-B325-897B5E20B17F}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {71D52BC7-CD96-4786-8802-12537870F73C}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {71D52BC7-CD96-4786-8802-12537870F73C}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {71D52BC7-CD96-4786-8802-12537870F73C}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {71D52BC7-CD96-4786-8802-12537870F73C}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {8F40200E-A0BE-4AED-913A-318DEB3428E7}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {8F40200E-A0BE-4AED-913A-318DEB3428E7}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {8F40200E-A0BE-4AED-913A-318DEB3428E7}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {8F40200E-A0BE-4AED-913A-318DEB3428E7}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {9AD909E2-6528-494D-83F3-E9F9BA21EA59}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {9AD909E2-6528-494D-83F3-E9F9BA21EA59}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {9AD909E2-6528-494D-83F3-E9F9BA21EA59}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {9AD909E2-6528-494D-83F3-E9F9BA21EA59}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {DF22E1D0-12B5-4AE1-8507-C20E250E824A}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {DF22E1D0-12B5-4AE1-8507-C20E250E824A}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {DF22E1D0-12B5-4AE1-8507-C20E250E824A}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {DF22E1D0-12B5-4AE1-8507-C20E250E824A}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {5957E137-84AE-4F53-9F7A-BCFD9AAF6947}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {5957E137-84AE-4F53-9F7A-BCFD9AAF6947}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {5957E137-84AE-4F53-9F7A-BCFD9AAF6947}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {5957E137-84AE-4F53-9F7A-BCFD9AAF6947}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {92E2BB7D-CA78-4759-9F96-3CA71AD62AD9}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {92E2BB7D-CA78-4759-9F96-3CA71AD62AD9}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {92E2BB7D-CA78-4759-9F96-3CA71AD62AD9}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {92E2BB7D-CA78-4759-9F96-3CA71AD62AD9}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {3169C948-DC41-4B05-8625-25F7D0D69026}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {3169C948-DC41-4B05-8625-25F7D0D69026}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {3169C948-DC41-4B05-8625-25F7D0D69026}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {3169C948-DC41-4B05-8625-25F7D0D69026}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {A0423A13-7426-4093-8BC9-D39FA3A5246D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {A0423A13-7426-4093-8BC9-D39FA3A5246D}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {A0423A13-7426-4093-8BC9-D39FA3A5246D}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {A0423A13-7426-4093-8BC9-D39FA3A5246D}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {3F4BD2C9-E968-4FDE-86F6-5AB739795420}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {3F4BD2C9-E968-4FDE-86F6-5AB739795420}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {3F4BD2C9-E968-4FDE-86F6-5AB739795420}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {3F4BD2C9-E968-4FDE-86F6-5AB739795420}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {C66C049D-6A02-4BF5-9E7F-00090A946D7D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {C66C049D-6A02-4BF5-9E7F-00090A946D7D}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {C66C049D-6A02-4BF5-9E7F-00090A946D7D}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {C66C049D-6A02-4BF5-9E7F-00090A946D7D}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {8B8FB296-1A96-4FAA-A982-A9B34BE9F241}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {8B8FB296-1A96-4FAA-A982-A9B34BE9F241}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {8B8FB296-1A96-4FAA-A982-A9B34BE9F241}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {8B8FB296-1A96-4FAA-A982-A9B34BE9F241}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {E7E90EC5-30A7-458D-A593-960F75755C91}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {E7E90EC5-30A7-458D-A593-960F75755C91}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {E7E90EC5-30A7-458D-A593-960F75755C91}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {E7E90EC5-30A7-458D-A593-960F75755C91}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {5A4798C6-EFE7-43DA-B3AF-1DA75715FD68}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {5A4798C6-EFE7-43DA-B3AF-1DA75715FD68}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {5A4798C6-EFE7-43DA-B3AF-1DA75715FD68}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {5A4798C6-EFE7-43DA-B3AF-1DA75715FD68}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {EA3B55B7-65A7-4B57-A249-7265DA83E942}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {EA3B55B7-65A7-4B57-A249-7265DA83E942}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {EA3B55B7-65A7-4B57-A249-7265DA83E942}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {EA3B55B7-65A7-4B57-A249-7265DA83E942}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {98750BF6-5FDE-4F82-B625-8C3B9DC9B065}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {98750BF6-5FDE-4F82-B625-8C3B9DC9B065}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {98750BF6-5FDE-4F82-B625-8C3B9DC9B065}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {98750BF6-5FDE-4F82-B625-8C3B9DC9B065}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {593FAB70-649A-4CDB-A145-3F0A58115A9D}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {593FAB70-649A-4CDB-A145-3F0A58115A9D}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {593FAB70-649A-4CDB-A145-3F0A58115A9D}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {593FAB70-649A-4CDB-A145-3F0A58115A9D}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {7DAAA607-FA2B-4039-9627-85870A8621F3}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {7DAAA607-FA2B-4039-9627-85870A8621F3}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {7DAAA607-FA2B-4039-9627-85870A8621F3}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {7DAAA607-FA2B-4039-9627-85870A8621F3}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {60DF8EA9-6C0D-4E70-8C9C-B14790196D15}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {60DF8EA9-6C0D-4E70-8C9C-B14790196D15}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {60DF8EA9-6C0D-4E70-8C9C-B14790196D15}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {60DF8EA9-6C0D-4E70-8C9C-B14790196D15}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {B3413D98-BAE0-48C1-A773-DBD13FE691C8}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {B3413D98-BAE0-48C1-A773-DBD13FE691C8}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {B3413D98-BAE0-48C1-A773-DBD13FE691C8}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {B3413D98-BAE0-48C1-A773-DBD13FE691C8}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {DFAD4741-9711-4446-BABE-BC6F8FAB07F5}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {DFAD4741-9711-4446-BABE-BC6F8FAB07F5}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {DFAD4741-9711-4446-BABE-BC6F8FAB07F5}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {DFAD4741-9711-4446-BABE-BC6F8FAB07F5}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution
        {6867E0E4-B740-453E-B195-25A9E2295ADA} = {17199618-C1A9-4A6F-9C00-70DF2E17ADEE}
        {5F79D2CF-1885-4389-B325-897B5E20B17F} = {17199618-C1A9-4A6F-9C00-70DF2E17ADEE}
        {71D52BC7-CD96-4786-8802-12537870F73C} = {17199618-C1A9-4A6F-9C00-70DF2E17ADEE}
        {8F40200E-A0BE-4AED-913A-318DEB3428E7} = {17199618-C1A9-4A6F-9C00-70DF2E17ADEE}
        {9AD909E2-6528-494D-83F3-E9F9BA21EA59} = {85C8C31B-D9BD-465D-8F3E-2AC4FF5C3095}
        {DF22E1D0-12B5-4AE1-8507-C20E250E824A} = {85C8C31B-D9BD-465D-8F3E-2AC4FF5C3095}
        {5957E137-84AE-4F53-9F7A-BCFD9AAF6947} = {85C8C31B-D9BD-465D-8F3E-2AC4FF5C3095}
        {92E2BB7D-CA78-4759-9F96-3CA71AD62AD9} = {6F0BE538-53B1-4551-BA7A-7F687900BCD6}
        {3169C948-DC41-4B05-8625-25F7D0D69026} = {6F0BE538-53B1-4551-BA7A-7F687900BCD6}
        {A0423A13-7426-4093-8BC9-D39FA3A5246D} = {6F0BE538-53B1-4551-BA7A-7F687900BCD6}
        {3F4BD2C9-E968-4FDE-86F6-5AB739795420} = {8FA14344-9768-4E6C-A735-3353867240AF}
        {C66C049D-6A02-4BF5-9E7F-00090A946D7D} = {D1C6BD19-0545-4D07-816A-F1A4281F0C6F}
        {8B8FB296-1A96-4FAA-A982-A9B34BE9F241} = {17199618-C1A9-4A6F-9C00-70DF2E17ADEE}
        {E7E90EC5-30A7-458D-A593-960F75755C91} = {6F0BE538-53B1-4551-BA7A-7F687900BCD6}
        {5A4798C6-EFE7-43DA-B3AF-1DA75715FD68} = {17199618-C1A9-4A6F-9C00-70DF2E17ADEE}
        {EA3B55B7-65A7-4B57-A249-7265DA83E942} = {6F0BE538-53B1-4551-BA7A-7F687900BCD6}
        {2A831C90-C09E-49B3-A948-BA43E6C16208} = {E506C5A9-8B4C-4D6C-9F4A-9B78A39BEF2A}
        {020D2761-F1E4-417B-AFEA-94FE65E6A40F} = {E506C5A9-8B4C-4D6C-9F4A-9B78A39BEF2A}
        {404CE659-A8CC-4807-9F1F-6E721B676A22} = {E506C5A9-8B4C-4D6C-9F4A-9B78A39BEF2A}
        {0B002E0E-AD56-4DD3-BF38-B15A53640391} = {E506C5A9-8B4C-4D6C-9F4A-9B78A39BEF2A}
        {36EF4B96-316C-4135-A8AE-D24DE5BA7725} = {E506C5A9-8B4C-4D6C-9F4A-9B78A39BEF2A}
        {BC8A449A-189B-48EF-AB6B-DD8680DE3DA4} = {E506C5A9-8B4C-4D6C-9F4A-9B78A39BEF2A}
        {C3065E25-438F-4093-B37B-3BC85B154E46} = {E506C5A9-8B4C-4D6C-9F4A-9B78A39BEF2A}
        {98750BF6-5FDE-4F82-B625-8C3B9DC9B065} = {17199618-C1A9-4A6F-9C00-70DF2E17ADEE}
        {593FAB70-649A-4CDB-A145-3F0A58115A9D} = {17199618-C1A9-4A6F-9C00-70DF2E17ADEE}
        {7DAAA607-FA2B-4039-9627-85870A8621F3} = {6F0BE538-53B1-4551-BA7A-7F687900BCD6}
        {60DF8EA9-6C0D-4E70-8C9C-B14790196D15} = {6F0BE538-53B1-4551-BA7A-7F687900BCD6}
        {B3413D98-BAE0-48C1-A773-DBD13FE691C8} = {6F0BE538-53B1-4551-BA7A-7F687900BCD6}
        {DFAD4741-9711-4446-BABE-BC6F8FAB07F5} = {6F0BE538-53B1-4551-BA7A-7F687900BCD6}
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityGlobals) = postSolution
        SolutionGuid = {C0D194EA-E094-4351-BF6E-AC5AF807BD72}
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Example Individual Project .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <UserSecretsId>XXXXXXX</UserSecretsId>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
        <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\..\CodeAnalysis.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
        <WarningsAsErrors />
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
        <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>..\..\CodeAnalysis.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
        <WarningsAsErrors />
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers" Version="6.0.0">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets" Version="7.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="SonarAnalyzer.CSharp" Version="8.44.0.52574">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
        <PackageReference Include="StyleCop.Analyzers" Version="1.1.118">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Tsp.Sizamina.App.EntityFramework\Tsp.Sizamina.App.EntityFramework.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Tsp.Sizamina.App.Graph\Tsp.Sizamina.App.Graph.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Tsp.Sizamina.App.Report\Tsp.Sizamina.App.Report.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Include="..\Tsp.Sizamina.App.ServiceBus\Tsp.Sizamina.App.ServiceBus.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Update="appsettings.Development.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
      <Content Update="appsettings.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
      <Content Update="appsettings.User.json">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </Content>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I've tried the following:

1. Use the dotnet uninstall tool from MS to remove SDK's and runtimes - [Uninstall Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool)
2. Install Visual Studio for Mac using installer - V17.4.3
3. Installed dotnet using `homebrew install dotnet`

I've done extensive googling to find a solution to this but have yet to come across one that works.

Any guidance here would be appreciated, I've been pulling my hair out with this.

Attached the `dotnet --info` command for reference
[image: Dotnet info from terminal]

Comment: What version of Visual Studio for Mac are you using to open the solution?

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition

Comment: Show the solution file

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 for Mac doesn't have editions. The current versions are 17.4.3 and 17.5 Preview.

Comment: @PMF, added the solution file,

Comment: @JonathanDodds sorry, I'm running 17.4.3

Comment: You should copy&paste the text instead of using screenshots. Besides, the text from the first screenshot cannot be read completely. We can only assume what it says. Anyway, from what I see it doesn't know that project `{9A19....7556}`. Do you have a project file (like .csproj) with that guid under `<ProjectTypeGuids>`? How did you get the solution files?

Comment: @Andrew Solution files contain a guid that indicates the type of project. This is different from the guid that is used as an identifier of the project. See [Project Type GUIDs](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/main/docs/opening-with-new-project-system.md#project-type-guids) and note that `9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556` is a guid for the 'new project system'.

Comment: @MatthewTilley I suspect a version mismatch issue with the available 'project system'. See "[Opening with the new project system](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/blob/main/docs/opening-with-new-project-system.md)". How was the solution file created? Was it created under the Windows OS? The version of MSBuild available with VS for Mac is an older version from the version available with VS on Windows.

Comment: Is the C# workload installed?  Can you create and run a C# hello world app?

Comment: @JonathanDodds The project has been passed on from a previous contractor so I can only assume how the solution file was created, but I am 100% sure it was created using a Windows OS.

Will have a look at the link you provided and see if it can help, thank you!

Comment: @PMF - I installed C# workload but still the same problem sadly :(

Comment: @JonathanDodds I've tried to force the solution file to load in the 'new' project system but still experiencing the same issues

Comment: @MatthewTilley I think you want the old project system. I think that the issue is that the 'new' project system is not yet available in the non-preview version of VS for Mac. Try the following: In the solution file replace `9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556` with `FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC`.

Comment: @JonathanDodds sadly still the same problem :( just the error message references the old project type GUID instead of the new one.